# JavaScript variable not accessible outside of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button

I have a function that gets the id of a button when it is clicked, and stores this id in a variable. The same variable cannot be accessed outside of this loop, as it either returns blank or 'undefined'. I have initialised this variable outside of the loop, made it a global variable, and still i cannot access the id that is stored. Please help!

Javascript Function

```
var button = '';
var buttonid = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var j = 0; j < buttonid.length; j++){
buttonid[j].onclick = function(e){
button = this.id;
 //can see variable is alert is here
//alert(button);

};
}
//cannot see variable if alert is here
//alert(button)
```

Comment: use `let` instead.

Comment: tried let and still doesn't work

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not sure whether it's a duplicate, the closure doesn't use `i`.

Comment: @Hannah Where exactly do you use `button`? Are you sure the button has already been clicked when you access it? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi - Wrong dupetarget, thanks.

Comment: Hannah - `button` will have the value `''` in the commented-out alert at the end of the code because the click hasn't happened yet, so none of your click handlers has been called. Your click handlers will be called if the user clicks one of the buttons. Trigger whatever it is you want to have happen from code inside the handler, rather than code after the loop.